# Drawbacks of executing code in an SQLAlchemy managed session and if so why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have seen different "patterns" in handling this case so I am wondering if one has any drawbacks comapred to the other.
So lets assume that we wish to create a new object of class `MyClass` and add it to the database. We can do the following:

```
    class MyClass:
        pass
    def builder_method_for_myclass():
        # A lot of code here..
        return MyClass()

    my_object=builder_method_for_myclass()
    with db.managed_session() as s:
        s.add(my_object)
```

which seems that only keeps the session open for adding the new object but I have also seen cases where the entire builder method is called and executed within the managed session like so:

```
    class MyClass:
        pass
    def builder_method_for_myclass():
        # A lot of code here..
        return MyClass()

    with db.managed_session() as s:
        my_object=builder_method_for_myclass()
```

are there any downsides in either of these methods and if yes what are they? Cant find something specific about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you build objects depending on objects fetched from a session you have to be in a session.  So a factory function can only execute outside a session for the simplest cases.  Usually you have to pass the session around or make it available on a thread local.

For example in this case to build a product I need to fetch the product category from the database into the session.  So my product factory function depends on the session instance.  The new product is created and added to the same session that the category is also in.  An implicit commit should also occur when the session ends, ie the context manager completes.

```
def build_product(session, category_name):  
    category = session.query(ProductCategory).where(
        ProductCategory.name == category_name).first()
    return Product(category=category)

with db.managed_session() as s:
   
    my_product = build_product(s, "clothing")
    s.add(my_product)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes that makes sense but in my case the new object build, does not require info about other objects stored in the database (in the real case I have, I only need an UUID for a foreign key which I already have without having to query). So given that the object I create does not need other objects to be fetched what drawbacks does each option have?

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter if the factory is called inside or outside the context manager.  Although using the objects after the context ends can cause issues like `DetachedInstanceError` if you try to reference attributes that were not previously loaded since there is no session to operate in.

Comment: These things usually only come up when some object leaks outside a session or in some web frameworks if you try to access unloaded data on objects in a template after a session ended in a view controller.  I guess I haven't seen many different patterns.  Usually its one session per isolated task (web request, job, etc) so you don't leak objects either outside the session or into other sessions.